# how to draw path into the view in android

Tags: android

Hi i need to draw a path simple lines to the canvas it should write out red rectangle with white lines.but it do not draw out nothing what m i missing.
my code:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();


       Paint paint = new Paint();

       paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
       paint.setColor(Color.RED);
       canvas.drawPaint(paint);
       Path path = new Path();
       //canvas.drawColor(Color.CYAN);

       for (int i = 5; i < 50; i++) {

           path.moveTo(4, i-1);
           path.lineTo(4, i);

       }
       path.close();

       paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
       paint.setPathEffect(null);
       paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
       paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

       canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            View iview =    inflater.inflate(R.layout.linear_layout, null);
            if(i == 0){
                iview.findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.distspeed);
            }
            if(i == 1){
                iview.findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hxmdist);
            }
            if(i == 2){
                iview.findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hxmspeeed);
            }

            iview.draw(canvas);

            realViewSwitcher.addView(iview);
        }
```

Comment: Not for me, but I found the solution, i had to create my own view and at onDraw procedure i was able to draw out the path

Answer (score 21, accepted):

i only post the working code:

modified activity:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

        MyView mView = new MyView(this,i);

        realViewSwitcher.addView(mView);
        }
```

myview:

```
public class MyView extends View {

    public MyView(Context context, int kolki) {
        super(context);

        if (kolki == 0){
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.distspeed);
        }
        if (kolki == 1){
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hxmdist);
        }
    }

    public void setBackgroundResource (int resid){
        super.setBackgroundResource(resid);
    } 

    public void onDraw(Canvas c){
        super.onDraw(c);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Path path = new Path();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        c.drawPaint(paint);
        for (int i = 50; i < 100; i++) {
               path.moveTo(i, i-1);
               path.lineTo(i, i);  
        }
        path.close();
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        paint.setPathEffect(null);
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        c.drawPath(path, paint);
    }

}
```

Comment: Allocating objects in `onDraw` is not recommended so the `Paint` and `Path` should be allocated in the constructor.